# How to save the selected datetime from DateTimeField in Flutter

Tags: flutter, datetime

I have used the below code to save the date time. It selects both date and time and displays the selected date and time in the textfield. But how do I save it in a variable or how do I save it in my database. I have 'note' table in database. I want to save the selected date and time in 'actn_on' column in 'note' table.

```
Text('Action on (${format.pattern})'),
    DateTimeField(
    format: format,
    onShowPicker: (context, currentValue) async {
    final date = await showDatePicker(
    context: context,
    firstDate: DateTime(1900),
    initialDate: currentValue ?? DateTime.now(),
    lastDate: DateTime(2100));
    if (date != null) {
    final time = await showTimePicker(
    context: context,
    initialTime:
    TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(currentValue ?? DateTime.now()),
      
    );
    return DateTimeField.combine(date, time);


    } else {
    return currentValue;
    }
    },
    ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At First, Declare a Controller,

```
final TextEditingController _timeController = TextEditingController();
```

then pass it to the

```
DateTimeField
```

like this

```
DateTimeField(
  controller: _timeController,
    ....
)
```

access it like `_timeController.text`

Or else `DateTimeField` also offer `onSaved`, to use this, first declare a variable `var _time` and then pass it like this

```
DateTimeField(
  onSaved: (val) => setState(() => _time = val),
   ....
    )
```

Comment: Even this is not working.

Comment: I tried printing action where action=_datetimecontroller.text but it prints nothing

Comment: Thankyou it worked !! Sorry I was trying it wrong first.  this is the right way --> note.actn_on=_datetimeController.text;

Comment: This is outdate, theres no controller parameter anymore. Are you able to update your answer please?

Answer (score 0):

I belive your answer is in this field:
`return currentValue;`
Just make a variable outside and assign `currentValue` to it.Like:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget{
String dt = ""; 
Widget build(BuildContext c){
// your code
.....
else {
dt = currentValue;
    return currentValue;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: No actually my value is in return DateTimeField.combine(date, time); right? I am trying all the methods to save it in a variable but to no avail.

Comment: Even  dt=currentValue shows the same error. to add a cast

Comment: currentValue - check type. `String dt` is just a proposition.